# year picker directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using datepicker from Angular directives for bootstrap. I want to show only specific (1900 -2020)years in the datePicker pop-up, but could not find a way.

I tried changing in yeraPicker directive which is called in datePicker directive,but no change is made.i am using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js...

Could you help me to find a way to give only specific years in yearPicker directive.

Comment: can you provide code sample what did you try to do? also, elaborate more on what 'give only specific years' do you mean?

Comment: specific years mean,,,,the year range what i want in drop down of yearPicker to be (1900-2020)....Presntly i am getting many years in a dropdown...i am unable to change the year range in that directive...

Comment: do you use that one https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker  ?

Comment: hmm yes...i am using this directive.....This is my html file <input ui-date="dateOptions".ng-model="date"/>....the problem is i could restrict the years by giving in my dateoptions as yearRange: '1900:2020'....but instead of changing in dateoptions yearRange....i want this range '1900:2020' to be changed in directive itself....i am unable to find exact place in the directive to make this change.

Comment: 'i want this range '1900:2020' to be changed in directive itself' - do you mean modify the original directive code?

Comment: hmm yes...Is it possible to make this change in the original directive??

Comment: you don't need to hardcode anything into the original directive code. You have a open API - Datepicker Settings (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) that you should use to customize the way it behaves

Comment: Thnq....so you are saying...we can only customize it through dateOptions of what i am doing now...but we cant make any changes to the directive...